Dotnet wrapper for google/jpegli
I want to create a wrapper in C# for google/jpegli.
I’m having trouble figuring out how to build the project to eventually get a DLL for creating the wrapper. I followed this guide: https://github.com/google/jpegli/blob/main/doc/developing_in_windows_vcpkg.md
In the end, I managed to compile the cjpegli.exe project and got several libraries, including jpeg62.dll and jpegli-static.lib. I examined jpeg62.dll, and it seems to contain only the API of the old libjpeg library.
I assume I should use jpegli-static.lib, but that would require creating a C++ DLL based on the library. I don't have much experience with C++, and my attempts to use jpegli-static.lib have been unsuccessful. Please help.

Start here : .NET programming with C++/CLI
This will allow you to create a managed C++ wrapper that will allow fine control over marshalling/lifetimes etc. (e.g. copying data from C++ heap to garbage collectedmemory, or pinning C++ memory etc etc.). So I am probably telling you it is not easy to make a stable wrapper without knowing at least a bit of C++ and how both .Net and C++ manage memory.

Also what does that library offer that .Net code cannot do?  E.g. Image.FromFile Method

it seems to contain only the API of the old libjpeg library - from the notes on the github page that you link to, it seems to be intended as a drop-in replacement for the standard library, so that's hardly surprising.
